# Changed primary domain and now wordpress login won't work

Tags: login

I changed the primary domain on a website I'm working on, but now when I go to wp-admin page and try to login it wont work. I assume this is because of this most recent change. Like changing something with my hosting company, is there somewhere in the FTP of wordpress that I have to update to tell it to now head to this new primary domain?

The website is working fine, I just can't login right now.

Any advice or suggestions on some change of files via FTP would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

All I did was add this to my wp-config file after the define('WP_DEBUG', true); command

```
define('WP_HOME','http://mydomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mydomain.com');
```

Comment: This will override home and site URL values from database. But you should also change those from database too.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already found, it's because the wp_home and wp_siteurl options in your database are set to the old domain. You can change these in your config file, or in the wp_options database table itself.

I would suggest you also do a find and replace over your database, otherwise links in your page content will continue to point to the old domain name.

This is a useful plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/